# Prove or disprove a claim regarding rational numbers

Tags: calculus, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I need to prove or disprove the following claim.
Let $ x \notin \Bbb Q $ such that $ x^3 \in \Bbb Q $. Then $x^2+x+1 \notin \Bbb Q$.
I tried to find a lot of counter examples in order to disprove it, yet couldn't find anything.
I was also unable to prove it.
Any assistance will be welcomed.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint:   $x^3\in \mathbb Q\implies x^3-1\in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x^2+x+1 \in \Bbb Q$. Because $x^3 \in \Bbb Q$, so is $x^3-1$.

We know $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1) $ (check it!), so $\frac{x^3-1}{x^2+x+1} = x-1 \in \Bbb Q$. Therefore $x \in \Bbb Q$. Which is a contradiction.

Note that $x^2+x+1=0$ has no real solution.